# Spring MVC, Form data retrieval and compare with the database

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm new to spring , can anybody explain how do we retrieve data from a form and after retrieving data we compare the data with the database and display message.

Comment: What you  have tried so far?

Comment: Initially i made a signup form and inserted data through it and then i made a login form and i'm not able to compare the form value with the database @Irshad

Comment: Old Post, was a new learner. Got it now.